How can I extend TypeORM QueryBuilder
I want to add custom method to typeorm query builder:
import { Column, Entity, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm'

@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id!: string

  @Column()
  name!: string
}

export const AppDataSource = new DataSource({
  ...config,
  entities: [User],
})


now I want to extend QueryBuilder and add some custom method to it
import { SelectQueryBuilder } from 'typeorm'

class CustomUserQueryBuilder extends SelectQueryBuilder<User> {
  constructor() {
    super(AppDataSource.createQueryBuilder())
    this.from(User, 'user')
  }
  async customLeftJonAndSelect() {
    return this.where(`...`)
  }
}

const customQb = new CustomUserQueryBuilder()
customQb.select('*').customLeftJonAndSelect().getQuery()

Problem is it keeps giving me this error:
EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "User" was found: this.from(User, 'user')
                                                                        ^

I really appreciate If anyone can help me how to acheive this or any idea on what am I doing wrong

Not sure exactly what's causing you're issue, because I too was trying to extend SelectQueryBuilder and came up with a solution more or less the same as yours. The following is my implementation.
export class MyQueryBuilder extends SelectQueryBuilder<MyEntity> {
  constructor(dataSource: DataSource) {
    super(
      dataSource
        .getRepository<MyEntity>()
        .createQueryBuilder('mine')
    );
  }

  async whereAlwaysTrue() {
    return this.where('1 = 1');
  }
}

I've not used the builder.from(...) method and am not very familiar with it, but I would say that whatever the issue is either relates to that call or the way your AppDataSource is configured.
Did you remember to run your migrations? Usually when I get the No metadata ... error it's because I forgot to generate/run the migration to add a table for the entity in question.
